# Cannot minify css using webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webpack

I would like to minify my css file for the production and I am using webpack 3 with the following configuration:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./src/index.tsx", "./src/assets/css/styles.css"
    ],

    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    // devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename:  (getPath) => {
              return getPath('assets/css/styles.css').replace('css/js', 'css');
            },
            allChunks: true
          }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
          assetNameRegExp: /\.styles\.css$/g,
          cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
          cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
            preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
          },
          canPrint: true
        })
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, use: ["awesome-typescript-loader"] },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { test: /\.js$/, enforce: "pre", use: "source-map-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                        { loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {} }
                      ]
              }
        ],

        loaders: [ {
            test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            loaders: [
                'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
            ]
        } ]
    }
};
```

Error:

> Module build failed: Error: Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find
>   module 'postcss-plugin'

I also have this postcssrc.js in the root of project:

```
module.exports = {
  parser: 'sugarss',
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'postcss-preset-env': {},
    'cssnano': {}
  }
}
```

I am all confused if I am using more than enought plugins just for a minification of css, anyone knows what the problem here or can guide me what do I need or change here?

Comment: You need to run Webpack in `production` mode, `npx webpack -p` in order to enable the minification

Comment: @felixmosh I am already running webpack in production mode using npm run-script build, which will run this webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js -p

Comment: Add `postcss-loader` to your dependencies ( `npm install postcss-loader` )

Comment: @drinchev i have it already